# Access denied for unpublished content in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

When i unpublished a content in drupal 7, I am getting an access denied message. But for some other unpublished content i am getting page not found message. I need page not found message to unpublished content. How can i do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [path redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) module ?
got some miracles done with it with old link or renamed one.